# Erroneous Circular Dependency exception - resolving components in a rapid sequence

Tags: c#, .net, exception, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I am using a factory to resolve components in Castle Windsor (with arguments) and it works fine normally. However, the (transient) instance creations are tied to an incoming event, and if the inter-event interval is too short then I get a circular dependency exception.

- Why? I should not be getting this exception based on the observation that the very same factory method works fine normally and given I do not believe to have any actual circular dependencies.

#### When Timings are Too Close / Object Creation Too Fast

This is the log to show the details, note that the two calls are very close in time (and need to be).

```
IProcessChanger CreateProcessChanger(int pid) 10472 @ 15:36:31.667
IProcessChanger CreateProcessChanger(int pid) 5700 @ 15:36:31.700
First Chance Exception in xxx.vshost.exe, sender Name:xxx.vshost.exe
There are no context policies.
! CircularDependencyException: Dependency cycle has been detected when trying to resolve component 'xxx.ProcessChanger'.
The resolution tree that resulted in the cycle is the following:
Component 'xxx.ProcessChanger' resolved as dependency of
    component 'xxx.ProcessChanger' which is the root component being resolved.
 @ 15:36:31.948
A first chance exception of type 'Castle.MicroKernel.CircularDependencyException' occurred in Castle.Windsor.dll
Unhandled Exception! CircularDependencyException: Dependency cycle has been detected when trying to resolve component 'xxx.ProcessChanger'.
The resolution tree that resulted in the cycle is the following:
Component 'xxx.ProcessChanger' resolved as dependency of
    component 'xxx.ProcessChanger' which is the root component being resolved.
 @ 15:36:32.013
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.ResolveCore(CreationContext context, Boolean requiresDecommission, Boolean instanceRequired, Burden& burden)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.Resolve(CreationContext context, Boolean instanceRequired)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.AbstractHandler.Resolve(CreationContext context)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.ResolveComponent(IHandler handler, Type service, IDictionary additionalArguments, IReleasePolicy policy)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Castle.MicroKernel.IKernelInternal.Resolve(Type service, IDictionary arguments, IReleasePolicy policy)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Resolve(Type service, IDictionary arguments)
   at Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.Resolve[T](IDictionary arguments)
   at xxx.BaseFactory.Create[T](Object[] arguments) ...
The program '[9116] xxx.vshost.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.
```

- How to fix it?

Comment: Are your calls to the factory method in separate threads?  Are you using the Typed Factory Facility?  Also, what are the dependencies of your concrete class that is being resolved?

Comment: @PatrickQuirk I started a clean project to try to replicate this issue but was unable to - I have tried to mimic most aspects I could think of from the complex project where the issue remains, but have not been able to raise the exception. This begs the question, under what circumstances would self-circularity occur as I have looked everywhere and do not see the class instantiating itself i.e. when in principle would this occur: Component 'xxx.ProcessChanger' resolved as dependency of component 'xxx.ProcessChanger' which is the root component being resolved ?